# Is there a way to switch from linux Ubuntu 18.04 back to windows 10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

title says it all, I have a laptop that was originally windows 10 and I switched it from windows 10 to ubuntu 18.04 using a usb with a copy of linux. Is there a way I can switch my laptop back to windows 10? I've searched the internet but there's very little answers to this topic and they're mostly outdated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Should be as simple as installing Windows 10 on the machine.  What part of that process are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: Yes. You will need a flash drive with the Windows 10 installer on it. You can download the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool (which is used to created a bootable USB installer) from Microsoft. You will need to use another Windows PC to create the USB. If you don't have access to a Windows PC, it's still possible, just a little more complicated.

Comment: Another windows PC isnt needed, in fact you can download the Windows 10 ISO from MS's website https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO , and use `dd` to write it to the USB. Maybe you can use Rufus over WINE if dd doesnt work but there's probably other Windows to USB installers on Linux.

Comment: dd is not recommended for making a bootable flash drive.

Comment: @K7AAY: If you google, many websites do advise to use `dd`. I also use `dd` for this purpose and have never had any problem. So why do you say `dd` is not recommended for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu explains how to make a Windows 10 installer USB flash drive on a Linux PC using [WoeUSB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu).

First, download the Wiindows 10 installation ISO from  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Install WoeUSB with

> sudo add-apt-repository universe # contains the p7zip-full dependency
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
>   sudo apt update && sudo apt install woeusb

Plug in the USB flash drive you will erase to make a Windows 10 installation flash drive.

Open a terminal, and find the name of the flash drive with

```
sudo lshw -class disk -short
```

Once you have the name of the USB flash drive ( /dev/sd**x* ) and use woeusb to create the installer with

```
sudo woeusb --device /path/to/your.iso /dev/sd**x**
```

Which walks you through the creation process.

Then, shut the PC down, and power back up; choose to boot from the USB flash drive instead of the internal drive, and you will start the normal Windows installation process for Windows 10.

Comment: Well I downloaded windows onto the USB from a separate PC, took me a few hours, then when I tried running `sudo lshw -class disk -short` the usb wasn't appearing. I searched it up and found out that I needed to format the usb first to be recongnized. I did just thing making sure that it would NOT clear the data on the usb. But then as soon as I clicked format all of the data on the usb was gone. Guess it's time to throw away this useless laptop with ubuntu on it.

Comment: Whoever said formatting the USB flash drive would not delete data on it? Silly. Flash drives must be formatted to work.

Comment: @Aidan If you created the flash drive with the Media Creation tool on another Windows PC, you are supposed to *boot* from that drive, not try to run it while booted in Ubuntu. It should be as simple as having the drive inserted while starting the computer up. There may be a F-key you need to press to get into the boot menu, which should then allow you to boot from the USB and reinstall Windows 10.